# I got a great job opportunity but did I apply too early?

Tags: job-offer, negotiation

I am working in the software engineering field, where I work in one of the top firms. I enjoy my current position, but after some minor remarks from management I decided to send my CV to some other firms, just to see if there were some interesting opportunities.

A few months have passed after that, and I just successfully interviewed in another very good firm and just received an offer from them. Eventually I feel I am not quite ready to leave my current position, and that maybe another 6 months or 1 year here would be nice, but this offer would be the perfect next step.

Should I take the offer, considering that this type of offer may not come by very often?

Or should I explain to that next company that I do not want to leave my current position at the moment but might be interested later, risking alienating them for good?

Comment: Take it now. Impostor syndrome is real. Believe me, if they picked you, it's because no one more qualified applied. Who knows if the market will still be this hot a year from now.

Answer (score 12):

“…this offer would be the perfect next step.“

Full stop, take it. If they are interviewing, they are looking to fill the role immediately. They will not wait 6-12 months for the possibility for you to renege.

Comment: Agreed.  You are in software, things change fast.  Part of a successful career in such is the ability to adapt.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately we can't decide for you but I think I would take it. If you were unhappy with your manager's comment, and you did nothing to bring it on or have nothing to "improve" upon (such as a generic response that you did "something" wrong just to be negative), then yes, you should take the offer. Don't expect such conditions to improve and will only worsen. I did it for 8 years.